# is there a way to access windows files from wsl besides /mnt/ everytime?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, subsystem

I need to call files from windows to use in wsl. how to do this from `/home/user/`?

Usually, I type `/mnt/c/users/etc` but this becomes time-consuming. Alternatively, I could just copy and paste a path but the dashes are always in the wrong direction. If there is a way to fix this it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a symbolic link in the root dir

```
sudo ln -s /mnt/c/users/etc /e
```

Now all you need to do to switch to this directory is `cd /e` from anywhere in the file system, minimal typing required.

Comment: Another way to go about it would be to do `sudo ln -s /mnt/c/ /c`, which means to access your user's home folder you would just need to do /c/users/yourUsername, which is similar to how Git Bash does it.